# VisualSearch.js : Is there a vanilla Javascript alternative to VisualSearch.js (Faceted Searching)?

Tags: javascript, angular, backbone.js, lodash, faceted-search

I have requirement in my project where I need something exactly similar to DocumentCloud's VisualSearch.js : 
https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/

This solution relies heavily on Backbone.js and Underscore.js( relies on APIs like _.any)

But my project is built in Angular 2 and lodash(latest version of lodash doesn't support _.any).

So, I am unable to integrate VisualSearch.js in my application.

Kindly guide if there are any alternatives or any way to use VisualSearch.js with my configuration.

It would be a great help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever find an alternative to VisualSearch?

Comment: nope.. not yet.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a suitable replacement for `VisualSearch` so I wrote my own. I call it `fancySearch`. No jQuery, BackBone, Underscore, or any other library was harmed in making `fancySearch`. Use it or improve it, do as you wish. I've put it in the public domain

Github: https://github.com/punkish/fancysearch
Demo and documentation: https://punkish.org/fancysearch/